# How can we limit scraping through tagName in Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, getelementsbytagname

I have the following code which scrapes questions from stack overflow. I used `tagName` locator to scrape a website. However, it scraped everything iniside the same tag, which includes things which are not needed. How to limit that?

For example, if i want to get just questions in h1 tag only The scraper will scrape questions with `stackoverflow` website's name also if in the h1 tag. How to make them scrape only questions in the specific tag?

**Here's my code which scrapes everything inside a tag. How to limit that?:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv

def to_do():
# vars...
    csv_file_location = r"C:\Users\intel\Desktop\data_file.csv"

    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
                 'Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36'

    driver_exe = 'chromedriver'
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
    options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
    options.add_argument("--allow-cross-origin-auth-prompt")

    url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions"

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\intel\Downloads\setups\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
    driver.get(url)

    one_ = "A"

    two_ = "DIV"

    three_ = "A"

    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, one_))
        )
        elements_1 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(one_)

        web_content_list = []
        for ele in elements_1:
            web_content_dict = {}
            web_content_dict["Title"] = ele.text
            web_content_list.append(web_content_dict)

        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, two_))
        )
        elements_2 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(two_)

        for ele2 in elements_2:
            web_content_dict = {}
            web_content_dict["Title2"] = ele2.text
            web_content_list.append(web_content_dict)

        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, three_))
        )

        elements_3 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(three_)

        for ele3 in elements_3:
            web_content_dict = {}
            web_content_dict["Title3"] = ele3.text
            web_content_list.append(web_content_dict)

        df = pd.DataFrame(web_content_list)
        new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1': df['Title'].dropna(),
                  'Column 2': df['Title2'].dropna(),
                  'Column 3': df['Title3'].dropna()})
        new_df.to_csv(csv_file_location,
                  index=False, mode='a', encoding='utf-8')

        try:
            f = open(csv_file_location)
            print("Done !!!\n"*3)

        except IOError:
            print("File not accessible")

        finally:
            f.close()
        driver.quit()

    except:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, one_))
        )
        elements_1 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(one_)

        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, two_))
        )

        elements_2 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(two_)

        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, three_))
        )

        elements_3 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(three_)

        df = pd.DataFrame({
            "Title1" : [ele for ele.text in elements_1],
            "Title2" : [ele2 for ele2.text in elements_2],
            "Title3" : [ele3 for ele3.text in elements_3],
        })
        df.to_csv(csv_file_location,
                  index=False, mode='w', encoding='utf-8')

        try:
            f = open(csv_file_location)
            print("Done !!!\n"*3)
            # Do something with the file
        except IOError:
            print("File not accessible")

        finally:
            f.close()
        driver.quit()

    finally:
        print("start")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    to_do()
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just get the a tags under questions, you can use this css selector:

```
selector = '#questions a'

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector))
        )

elements_1 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(selector)
```

This css selector will find the id of 'questions' and all anchor ('a') tags underneath it and only use those.

if you only want the question and none of the other anchor tags then modify the selector to use this:

```
selector = '#questions h3 a'
```

Comment: Okay so you mean adding hashtag `#` before the class name?? And then add the tags afterwards? @RKelley

Comment: Yes.  When using css selector placing a # in front of a word makes the search for an id of an element.  A period in front of a word makes the search for a class name.  When searching for a tag name, you just need to use the tag name without anything in front.

Comment: Well it's returning me an error. I used css selectors for this. I used `.question-hyperlink a` for scraping the headings of questions on stack overflow. Can you please check that? 

Comment: The element that you appear to be targeting would use the css selector of 'a.question-hyperlink'.  This means find an anchor tag ('a') that has the class name of 'question-hyperlink'.  When you separate them like '.question-hyperlink a' what happens is it searches for an element with class name of 'question-hyperlink' and then looks for a child element with the tag 'a' which on this page does not exist.

Comment: Well it's  returning me another error, but not with scraping. I used ```"Title1" : pd.Series([ ele for ele.text in elements ])``` for storing data to csv file, but returns me error that `name ele not defined` while converting element to `.text` . When i remove `.text`, then it runs fine. What is happening with usage of `.text`?

Comment: I can't tell what is happening exactly without the latest code, but just to go off what you say in the comment it appears that ele is probably null so there would be no .text property giving you the error, but null is able to be processed otherwise.  why that's happening?  I would need more to determine that.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response. Here's my code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61113227/selenium-unable-to-put-scraped-elements-to-csv