# Selenium : Unable to put scraped elements to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have successfully scraped the data from the site. Well it's returning me error.

I used `"Title1" : pd.Series([ ele for ele.text in elements ])` for storing data to csv file, but returns me error that `name "ele"` not defined when i use element to `.text` method .

When i remove `.text`, then it runs fine. But stores the id's which are not in form of text, so that's why i used `.text`. What is happening with usage of `.text`?

**Here is my code :**

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, x))
)
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(x)

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, y))
)
elements2 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(y)

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, z))
)
elements3 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(z)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Title1" : pd.Series([ ele for ele.text in elements ]),
    "Title2" : pd.Series([ ele2 for ele2.text in elements2 ]),
    "Title3" : pd.Series([ ele3 for ele3.text in elements3 ]),
})

df.to_csv(csv_file_location,
          index=False, mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
```

Just remove the text and see that it works fine and stores all the data to csv but not as text. Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: I think you meant to do `[ ele.text for ele in elements ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method `.text()`  is simply used to fetch an array/list of elements. In this line for example,

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(x)
```

This is why your loop `pd.Series([ ele for ele.text in elements ]),` fails, and so removing the text runs fine as expected.

So change this

```
pd.Series([ ele for ele.text in elements ])
```

to this

```
pd.Series([ ele.text for ele in elements ])
```

This means that it would first obtain `ele` first in `elements` and within that obtain the `text` attribute of the `ele`.